# C# Sql Textbox Select

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Hello :) I have a winform (c#) app that is connected to a sql server database that records the name, score and date of players who have played the app game. My problem is this: I have 2 textboxes, in which I want to enter a start date and an end date. How do I do the select in order for it to return only users who have played between the 2 textboxes' entered dates? I currently get an error saying that I must declare scalar variable `@Param`.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ssr;
        SqlConnection scr = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Highscore;Integrated Security=True");
        scr.Open();
        ssr = "Select Nume,Scor,DataInitiala,DataRecenta FROM Users where DataInitiala between @Param and @Param1 ";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(ssr, scr);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", from.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", to.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(ssr, scr);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adapter1.Fill(ds1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();  


    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far

Comment: Please add table schema also.

Comment: You have implemented parameters in your code, but aren't using them in your `ssr` string?

Comment: it is a leftover from something else..don't mind it

Comment: And what is the issue you are experiencing? You're well on your way with your code; however, help can't be given unless you explain your issue clearly to us and how it differs from expected result.

Comment: I want to run a select that will return players that played in the interval that is given in the 2 textboxes...and what I have now does not work

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any info about the problem you have so I assume the thing you forgot is adding the required `'`s around the `from.Text` and `to.Text` in your select command. Also, you should use Date validation to validate if the given text is a date.

```
            DateTime dtfrom;
            DateTime dtto;

            if(DateTime.TryParse(from.Text,out dtfrom) && DateTime.Parse(to.Text,out dtto);)
            {

                string from = dtfrom.ToShortDateString();
                string to = dtto.ToShortDateString();
            }
            else
            {
                //Parsing Error
            }
```

Your select command should be:

`Select Nume,Score,Ora,LunaAn,UpdatedData FROM TEST3 where LunaAn between '" + from + "' and '" + to + "';"`